# In-App Payment, is it possible to save a list of user's credit card in Android App

Tags: square

I'm trying to build up an android platform that takes in user credit card info and charge it on use without inserting the credit card details after saving one. But I don't seem to actually see any possible work ways in the "In-App Payment" SDK and I think I see it under Square's java SDK. But as researched in github, their official reply is that I'm unable to use java SDK in android app.

So I'm trying to figure out has anyone done this before or face the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-App Payments SDK is solely meant for generating a card nonce on your mobile application. All other API endpoints must be done on a server or service due to security reasons (you don't want to store your personal access token within your application). Once you have that nonce, you need a server or service running that your mobile application will talk to. Ie the most basic is passing the nonce to the `Charge` endpoint to charge a customer.

On that same note, we have another endpoint called `CreateCustomerCard`, which you can pass the `nonce` as well as `customer_id` to in order to save the card to this particular customer's profile. So, at the very least you'll need to create a customer in order to have their `id`.

For info around saving cards on file, see this post: [Hot to generate card nonce for repeated transactions without making users to enter card details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397261/hot-to-generate-card-nonce-for-repeated-transactions-without-making-users-to-ent)